# Call Web API using jquery AJAX in ASP.NET MVC 5 getting error

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I added the web api to the project that was available.
my api controller :

```
    namespace MyApplication.Controllers
{
    public class TaskApiController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Create(string UserName, string Password, string DoingDateTime, int ReferenceFrom, int ReferenceTo, string MaturityDateTime = "", int? PersonCompany_AffiliationID = null, int? SubjectID = null, string Description = "", int? ImportanceDegreeID = null, int? StatusID = null, int CompletionPercentage = 0, int? DossierID = null)
        {
            ...
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

add below code to web.config:

```
    <system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

and ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'localhost:3641/api/TaskApi',
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        UserName: 'admin',
                        Password: '123',
                        Description: 'test',
                        DoingDateTime: '1397/12/10',
                        ReferenceFrom: 2,
                        ReferenceTo: 2
                    },
                    type: 'Post',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('success');
                    }
            , error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
        });
```

when i test web api in browser with:

http://localhost:3641/api/TaskApi?UserName=admin&Password=312&Description=hkj&DoingDateTime=1397/02/05&ReferenceFrom=2&ReferenceTo=2

It works correctly. but when aun ajax it return error and   response.responseText returns "undefined".

Comment: if you set the Parameters in the body, you should expect a Object in WebApi with FromBody-Attribute.

Comment: @Nikolaus: i change action to:
public IHttpActionResult PostNewTask([FromBody] string UserName, [FromBody] string Password, [FromBody] string DoingDateTime, [FromBody] int ReferenceFrom, [FromBody] int ReferenceTo, [FromBody] string MaturityDateTime = "", [FromBody] int? PersonCompany_AffiliationID = null, [FromBody] int? SubjectID = null, [FromBody] string Description = "", [FromBody] int? ImportanceDegreeID = null, [FromBody] int? StatusID = null, [FromBody] int CompletionPercentage = 0, [FromBody] int? DossierID = null)
but still return "undefined" error

Comment: @Miss you cannot have more than one [FromBody].The [reason](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) for this rule is that the request body might be stored in a non-buffered stream that can only be read once.

Comment: Are you working with Visual Studio?

Comment: @Nikolaus : yes

Comment: Maybe you should debug and look in the output-Tab of VS, if there is a Exception thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest and cleaner way to solve your issue is to create a Viewmodel.

Also remember, for **complex types** Web Api by default reads the value from the message body, using a media-type formatter.

```
 public class TaskViewModel
 {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string DoingDateTime { get; set; }
        public int ReferenceFrom { get; set; }
        public int ReferenceTo { get; set;  }
        public string MaturityDateTime { get; set; }
        public int? PersonCompany_AffiliationID { get; set; }
        public int? SubjectID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int? ImportanceDegreeID { get; set; }
        public int? StatusID { get; set; }
        public int CompletionPercentage { get; set; }
        public int? DossierID { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Create(TaskViewModel taskViewModel)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       return BadRequest("");
   }
            return Ok();
}
```

Comment: I‘m not sure, complex types are always read from body, by default. I‘ve already had an issue, where I had to set the FromBodyAttribute explicitly.

Comment: @Nikolaus: Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: I tested with OP's AJAX code with the above solution and it worked. There might be a different issue going on we are unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

With your class, I wrote an AJAX, but it still fails.

```
var task = new Object();

task.Description = 'kjk';
task.PersonCompany_AffiliationID = null;
task.SubjectID = null;
task.DoingDateTime = '1397/12/11';
task.MaturityDateTime = null;
task.ImportanceDegreeID = null;
task.StatusID = null;
task.CompletionPercentage = 0;
task.ReferenceFrom = 2;
task.ReferenceTo = 2;
task.DossierID = null;



var req = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3641/api/TaskApi',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: task,
    type: 'Post',
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success');
    }
    , error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
});
```

What I noticed is an error due to the way information is sent to the action ...
I put a breakpoint on the first line of action, but the program does not go into action.

Comment: what was the error? also check on the network tabs on dev tools to see where it is posted

Comment: When I add [FromUri] to the action, executing the action will call the action, but value of all of the parameters are empty or null

Comment: Could you try remote debugging, as described in this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the dear ones who guide me

Problems solved with two things:
1- One of the mandatory fields in the model was not initialized in the AJAX
2- In other words, the data value is set to JSON.stringify (task)